# Measuring cudaMemcpy clock cycles

Tags: cuda, gpu, clock

I want to know how to measure the clock cycles spent in cudaMemcpy.

- If cudaMemcpy uses only CPU, it is ok, I just need to measure the CPU clock.
- But if it uses GPU, how can I measure how much clock cycles were spent in the copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cudaMemcpy` is a function, ultimately serviced by the GPU driver, which sets up a DMA operation to transfer data between Host and GPU.  The GPU driver is host code, so you can use host-based methods, or the `cudaEvent` system, to time the duration of e.g. `cudaMemcpy`.

Asynchronous versions e.g. `cudaMemcpyAsync` cannot usually be timed by themselves, because they set up the DMA operation and then immediately return to the calling thread (on the host).  The DMA operation occurs some time later.  Therefore you would need to insert additional synchronization (e.g. `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`) to time the duration of these.  Since that is usually not what you want, the usual recommendation in this case is to use either the `cudaEvent` system or one of the [profiling tools](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#axzz33UagRhMY).

Comment: So, if I want to see the clock cycles spent I just need to see in it in CPU code? :)

Comment: For CPU clock cycles, yes.  I'm not sure it makes sense to talk about GPU clock cycles in this context.

Comment: Robert, you can use CUDA events to measure asynchronous memcpy performance - although those measurements are only useful in the synchronous NULL stream.

Comment: Thanks Robert, you answered my question when you said that it should be measured in host code.